# HTML, CSS and JS not linking properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a quiz using the code from **[this codepen](http://codepen.io/kkoutoup/pen/ByGEoQ)** (code posted in snippet below).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //get total of questions
  var $questionNumber = $('h2').length;
  console.log($questionNumber);
  //caching final score
  var $totalScore = 0;

  $('li').click(function() {
    //caching variables
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    var $span = $(this).find('.fa');

    //deactivate options on click
    $parent.find('li').off("click");

    //check for .correct class
    //if yes
    if ($(this).hasClass('correct')) {
      //add .correctAnswer class
      $(this).addClass('correctAnswer');
      //find next span and change icon
      $span.removeClass('fa fa-square-o').addClass('fa fa-check-square-o');
      //reduce opacity of siblings
      $(this).siblings().addClass('fade');
      //show answer
      var $answerReveal = $parent.next('.answerReveal').show();
      var $toShowCorrect = $answerReveal.find('.quizzAnswerC');
      var $toShowFalse = $answerReveal.find('.quizzAnswerF');
      $toShowCorrect.show();
      $toShowFalse.remove();
      //add 1 to total score
      $totalScore += 1;
      //console.log($totalScore);
    } else {
      //add .wrongAnswer class
      $(this).addClass('wrongAnswer').addClass('fade');
      //change icon
      $span.removeClass('fa fa-square-o').addClass('fa fa-check-square-o');
      //reduce opacity of its siblings
      $(this).siblings().addClass('fade');
      //show wrong Message
      var $answerReveal = $parent.next('.answerReveal').show();
      var $toShowCorrect = $answerReveal.find('.quizzAnswerC');
      var $toShowFalse = $answerReveal.find('.quizzAnswerF');
      $toShowCorrect.remove();
      $toShowFalse.show();
      //locate correct answer and highlight
      $parent.find('.correct').addClass('correctAnswer');
    };
  }); //end click function

  //print Results
  function printResult() {
    var resultText = '<p>';
    if ($totalScore === $questionNumber) {
      resultText += 'You got ' + $totalScore + ' out of ' + $questionNumber + '! </p>';
      $('.resultContainer').append(resultText);
      $('#halfText').append('<p>This is awesome!</p>');
      $('#halfImage').append('<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100%"><img>');
    } else if ($totalScore >= 3 && $totalScore < $questionNumber) {
      resultText += 'You got ' + $totalScore + ' out of ' + $questionNumber + '! </p>';
      $('.resultContainer').append(resultText);
      $('#halfText').append('<p>So and so...better luck next time</p>');
      $('#halfImage').append('<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100%"><img>');
    } else if ($totalScore < 3) {
      resultText += 'You got ' + $totalScore + ' out of ' + $questionNumber + ' </p>';
      $('.resultContainer').append(resultText);
      $('#halfText').append('<p>No..no...no...you have to try harder</p>');
      $('#halfImage').append('<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100%"><img>');
    }

  }; //end function

  //final score
  $('ul').last().click(function() {
    //prevent further clicks on this
    $(this).off('click');
    //show result after last li is clicked
    var $height = $('.finalResult').height();
    printResult();
    $('.finalResult').show();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height() - $height
      },
      1400);
  });

}); //end dom ready
```

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
 body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.inner {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
/*********************** LIST ***********************/

.simpleListAnswer:hover {
  /*background:#fff195;*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
.simpleListAnswer,
.quizzAnswer {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 9px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
.simpleListText {
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #3d3d3d;
}
/***************************ANSWER REVEAL******************/

.quizzAnswerC,
.quizzAnswerF,
.finalResult {
  background: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.answerReveal {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.answerHeader div {
  color: #84f272;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#bravo,
#sorry {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.answerHeader {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
h3.correctMessage {
  color: #88f078;
  font-size: 30px;
}
h3.wrongMessage {
  color: #ff1f1f;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.fa.fa-check-circle,
.fa.fa-times-circle {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.correctAnswer {
  background: #88f078;
}
.wrongAnswer {
  background: #ff1f1f;
}
.fade {
  opacity: .6;
  cursor: default;
}
/*************************FINAL RESULT******************************/

.finalResult {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: none;
}
.finalResult h4 {
  color: #797979;
}
.resultContainer p {
  font-size: 25px;
}
#halfText,
#halfImage {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#halfImage {
  margin-top: -40px;
}
#halfImage img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">

      <h1>How much do you think you know about stuff?</h1>

      <h2>Who discovered America?</h2>
      <ul class="simpleList">
        <li class="simpleListAnswer correct">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">Christopher Columbus</span>
        </li>

        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">My grandma</span>
        </li>
        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">Yes,please</span>
        </li>
        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">Who's this on the phone again?</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--end simpleList-->

      <div class="answerReveal">

        <div class="quizzAnswerC">
          <div class="answerHeader">
            <h3 class="correctMessage"><i class="fa fa-check-circle "></i>Correct! </h3>
          </div>
          <!--end answer header-->
          <div class="answerText">
            <p id="bravo">Your answer is correct on so many levels! Well done!</p>
          </div>
          <!--end asnwerText-->
        </div>
        <!--end quizzAnswerC-->

        <div class="quizzAnswerF">
          <div class="answerHeader">
            <h3 class="wrongMessage"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>Sorry</h3>
          </div>
          <!--end answer header-->
          <div class="answerText">
            <p id="sorry">This is not the answer we were looking for...</p>
          </div>
          <!--end asnwerText-->
        </div>
        <!--end quizzAnswerF-->
      </div>
      <!--end answerReveal-->

      <h2>What is 2 x 4?</h2>
      <ul class="simpleList">
        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">Pasta</span>
        </li>

        <li class="simpleListAnswer correct">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">8</span>
        </li>
        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">232.456</span>
        </li>
        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">1</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--end simpleList-->

      <div class="answerReveal">

        <div class="quizzAnswerC">
          <div class="answerHeader">
            <h3 class="correctMessage"><i class="fa fa-check-circle "></i>Correct! </h3>
          </div>
          <!--end answer header-->
          <div class="answerText">
            <p id="bravo">Your answer is correct on so many levels! Well done!</p>
          </div>
          <!--end asnwerText-->
        </div>
        <!--end quizzAnswerC-->

        <div class="quizzAnswerF">
          <div class="answerHeader">
            <h3 class="wrongMessage"><i class="fa fa-times-circle  "></i>Sorry</h3>
          </div>
          <!--end answer header-->
          <div class="answerText">
            <p id="sorry">This is not the answer we were looking for...</p>
          </div>
          <!--end asnwerText-->
        </div>
        <!--end quizzAnswerF-->
      </div>
      <!--end answerReveal-->

      <h2>How many tires do you have to buy if you have 2 cars in the family?</h2>
      <ul class="simpleList">
        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">10</span>
        </li>

        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">We don't have a car</span>
        </li>
        <li class="simpleListAnswer correct">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">8</span>
        </li>
        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">12</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--end simpleList-->

      <div class="answerReveal">

        <div class="quizzAnswerC">
          <div class="answerHeader">
            <h3 class="correctMessage"><i class="fa fa-check-circle "></i>Correct! </h3>
          </div>
          <!--end answer header-->
          <div class="answerText">
            <p id="bravo">Your answer is correct on so many levels! Well done!</p>
          </div>
          <!--end asnwerText-->
        </div>
        <!--end quizzAnswerC-->

        <div class="quizzAnswerF">
          <div class="answerHeader">
            <h3 class="wrongMessage"><i class="fa fa-times-circle  "></i>Sorry</h3>
          </div>
          <!--end answer header-->
          <div class="answerText">
            <p id="sorry">This is not the answer we were looking for...</p>
          </div>
          <!--end asnwerText-->
        </div>
        <!--end quizzAnswerF-->
      </div>
      <!--end answerReveal-->

      <h2>If a jar of marmelade costs $3 how much do 12 jars of marmelade cost?</h2>
      <ul class="simpleList">

        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">Batman</span>
        </li>

        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">$30</span>
        </li>
        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">Can I have Nutella instead?</span>
        </li>
        <li class="simpleListAnswer correct">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">$36</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--end simpleList-->

      <div class="answerReveal">

        <div class="quizzAnswerC">
          <div class="answerHeader">
            <h3 class="correctMessage"><i class="fa fa-check-circle "></i>Correct! </h3>
          </div>
          <!--end answer header-->
          <div class="answerText">
            <p id="bravo">Your answer is correct on so many levels! Well done!</p>
          </div>
          <!--end asnwerText-->
        </div>
        <!--end quizzAnswerC-->

        <div class="quizzAnswerF">
          <div class="answerHeader">
            <h3 class="wrongMessage"><i class="fa fa-times-circle  "></i>Sorry</h3>
          </div>
          <!--end answer header-->
          <div class="answerText">
            <p id="sorry">This is not the answer we were looking for...</p>
          </div>
          <!--end asnwerText-->
        </div>
        <!--end quizzAnswerF-->
      </div>
      <!--end answerReveal-->

      <h2>Which planet is nearest the sun?</h2>
      <ul class="simpleList">

        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">Venus</span>
        </li>

        <li class="simpleListAnswer correct">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">Mercury</span>
        </li>
        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">The Moon</span>
        </li>
        <li class="simpleListAnswer">
          <span class="fa fa-square-o"></span>
          <span class="simpleListText">Earth</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--end simpleList-->

      <div class="answerReveal">

        <div class="quizzAnswerC">
          <div class="answerHeader">
            <h3 class="correctMessage"><i class="fa fa-check-circle "></i>Correct! </h3>
          </div>
          <!--end answer header-->
          <div class="answerText">
            <p id="bravo">Your answer is correct on so many levels! Well done!</p>
          </div>
          <!--end asnwerText-->
        </div>
        <!--end quizzAnswerC-->

        <div class="quizzAnswerF">
          <div class="answerHeader">
            <h3 class="wrongMessage"><i class="fa fa-times-circle  "></i>Sorry</h3>
          </div>
          <!--end answer header-->
          <div class="answerText">
            <p id="sorry">This is not the answer we were looking for...</p>
          </div>
          <!--end asnwerText-->
        </div>
        <!--end quizzAnswerF-->
      </div>
      <!--end answerReveal-->


      <div class="finalResult">
        <h4>How much do you think you know about stuff?</h4>
        <div class="resultContainer"></div>
        <div id="halfText"></div>
        <div id="halfImage"></div>
      </div>
      <!--end finalResult-->

    </div>
    <!--end inner-->
  </div>
  <!--end container-->
</body>
```

And I have put it into a separate HTML, CSS and JavaScript file and linked them all however when I upload it to my server, none of the buttons actually let me click on them, and it doesn't show the right or wrong answers.

Is there any obvious reason I'm missing here?

Comment: have you downloaded jquery?

Comment: on the codepen link where it says  <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>

Replace this with 
```<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>``` and it should work

Comment: Look in the browser's JavaScript console. Are there errors there? Then look in the console's network tab. Are all files loaded correctly?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Adding an `http://` at the beginning should be safest.

Comment: it works perfectly for me, I am assuming it is the jquery issue. Use the google CDN from this page http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: @Xufox I actually copied it so there would be a ```http``` but for some reason it was reformatted in the comment. I have fixed this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codepen automatically sources jQuery for you, however if you are copying the code directly you will be missing the jQuery reference.

All you need to do is modify the HTML where it reads:

`<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>`

and change the entire element to:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you so much dude! I'm an idiot can't believe I missed this.